# Traversing a linked list by 1

Tags: c, linked-list

Every time we allocate memory for linked list in heap we get an address and this address is linked to the next variable of linked list and head is a pointer which pointer to beginner node of linked list.

If we do `head = head + 1` than it points to next linked list or it points to random memory of heap or it points to the next memory of beginner list in the heap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it points to a memory area right after the first element, which you shouldn't be accessing.

I think you're confusing the concept of array with linked list. If you use an array, then `head = head + 1` would have given you the next element in the array. But on a linked list every member has a different location in memory, and the only way to get that location is by dereferencing the previous element's `next` member

Answer (score 0):

> If we do head = head + 1 than it points to next linked list or it points to random memory of heap or it points to the next memory of beginner list in the heap.

Provided that `head` initially points to a valid object of the correct type, after that statement, `head` points just past the end of the object to which it initially pointed.  That might or might not make it a pointer to the next node, depending on numerous factors, some of them out of your control, but typically the new value of `head` is *not* a pointer to the next node.

The addition operation knows nothing about the significance of the object to which `head` initially points.  It is the same operation for a pointer of any type.